# Trigger query on child object

Tags: trigger

I have a parent object named `Incident__c` and child object named `Pending_Customer__c`.

One `Incident__c` record for one or many `Pending_Customer__c` records

When the `Incident__c` record field `status__c` is set to "Pending - Customer" and any child `Pending_Customer__c` records have a blank `End_Date_Time__c` field (only one will ever be blank) Update the `End_Date_Time__c` with the value of NOW

I'd like to use a trigger to write this, but don't know where to start

Comment: Have you tried the Salesforce [trigger trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers)? If not, I'd suggest trying it, and some of the other Apex Basics trailheads, and [editing](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/162237/edit) your question to include some code you've written afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Process Builder` here, no `Apex` required!

1. Create a `Process Builder` flow on the `Incident__c` object.
2. Add a criteria formula that detects when `Status__c` changes to `"Pending - Customer"`.

   ```
   AND(ISCHANGED(Status__c), ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Pending - Customer"))
   ```
3. Add an `Immediate Action` to **Update Records**.

   - Select a record related to the Incident -> choose the `Pending_Customers__r` related list.
   - Set Criteria for Updating Records to check for your Datetime field being null.
   - Add your field update to set the Datetime field to `NOW()`.

Comment: 1,000,000 times better than what I wrote. Clicks not code! :) +1

Comment: In our org we often have to re-implement the Process Builders (PB) that admins have created into triggers due to performance issues and `Apex CPU time limit exceeded` error, that's why I always opt for a trigger initially. However, if the object that is being watched by a PB won't be a part of heavy calculation and large bulk updates, then a PB is a good enough solution. That's just an opinion based on my experience so far.

Comment: @smukov Yes absolutely correct. My assessment here is that it seems unlikely to be a bulk action which triggers this flow, but when performance is a must, PB is out. It's good to see both approaches. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson how will this work if i only want to find pending_customer__c records? (of which there could be multiple), and only want to update the record containing the empty end_date_time__c field?

Comment: @Glenn that's why you add criteria to the update.

Comment: @AdrianLarson superb, what a dumbarse!

Answer (score 2):

```
trigger IncidentTrigger on Incident__c (after update){

    //keep a set of Ids for all Incident__c records that have
    //an updated Status__c == 'Pending - Customer'
    Set<Id> incidentIds = new Set<Id>()
    for(Incident__c in : Trigger.new){
        if(in.Status__c == 'Pending - Customer' 
            && Trigger.oldMap.get(in.Id).Status__c != in.Status__c){
            incidentIds.add(in.Id)
        }
    }

    if(incidentIds.size() == 0){
        return;
    }

    List<Pending_Customer__c> customersToUpdate = new List<Pending_Customer__c>();

    //now get the child records (Pending_Customer__c) of these Incident__c records, 
    //iterate through them and set the End_Date_Time__c field 
    //for any record that has a blank End_Date_Time__c field
    for(Pending_Customer__c customer : [
        SELECT Id, End_Date_Time__c 
        FROM Pending_Customer__c
        WHERE Incident__c IN :incidentIds
    ]){

        if(customer.End_Date_Time__c == null){
            customer.End_Date_Time__c = System.now();
            customersToUpdate.add(customer);
        }                             
    }

    //finally, update the child records
    update customersToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Just  **(1)**. thing, `if(incidentIds.size() == 0){` - I believe this check is unnecessary as the SOQL of ChildObj will return nothing when `id in null` will be queried. Removing this check will save you CPU time.

Comment: @Mahmood but will I consume 1 uneccessary SOQL query?

Comment: No you won't , nothing else changes in your code.

Comment: @Mahmood, I just tried this in apex anonymous and 1 SOQL query actually got consumed. I created a question/answer for this if you want to chip in: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162261/does-soql-query-get-consumed-when-quering-from-an-empty-set

Comment: My bad. I mixed up with DMLs. :)

Comment: @Mahmood, no problem. You made me check, and now I'm sure how it works! :)