# Does SOQL query get consumed when querying from an empty set?

Tags: soql, governorlimits

Let's say I have a following piece of code:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Contact c : [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds]){
    System.debug(c);
}
```

The `accountIds` set is obviously empty in the example above, but will my Apex code consume 1 SOQL query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, even though the `Set<Id> accountIds` is empty, 1 SOQL query will be executed and will be counted against the 100 SOQL queries limit.

On a similar note, the code below won't be counted as 1 DML statement:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
update accounts;
```

Comment: Thats why, before firing SOQL query better to check the size of Collection, where as in case of DML, no need to check isEmpty()

Comment: Not too surprising as the where clause could be e.g. `NOT IN :accountIds`.

Answer (score 1):

To check the **SOQL** consumption if an  **empty collection** is passed in **WHERE** clause, I ran below code, also making a **DML** in the last line (to check both SOQL and DML)

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
// passing empty collection of ids (accountIds) to feed the below SOQL
Account[] accnts = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accountIds];
DELETE accnts;
```

and got this result

```
Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
...
```

So, working with **empty collection** in such scenario, the results suggest that

1. One SOQL will be consumed and count against SOQL limits, hence an `if(collection.size())` check should be placed to check the size of the **collection** before feeding it to the **SOQL** to avoid counting against SOQL limits.
2. No DML will be counted, which means, `if(collection.size())` check would be an **unnecessary** before the DML statement.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the question.

Comment: Yeah @adrian I know, I'm on mobile and will update the answer to include the soql consumption and result asap. Thanks btw.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: done.

Comment: Saw it already and voted to even things out a bit. FYI I didn't place either down-vote, but this answer doesn't really *add* anything not already there in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. You just made it to my list-of-liked-persons, top 1%. :D
As for the answer, I thought about removing but then I thought why not present some solution to the problems (efficiency wise) surrounding this question. **Results** at the end should give the reader something to look-out for and avoid at the same time to make things efficient and stay safe with the SFDC  limits.