# Does a SOQL Query that returns 0 results still count toward Query Governor Limit?

Tags: soql, query, governorlimits

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is yes, but was hoping to get community confirmation of that since I can't find any post asking the question or any documentation specifically indicating one or the other.

Let's say I have the following map in my class, which gets its values by passing a list of contacts to the CommunityUsersManagerUtil - but sometimes that list being passed to the method (`contactsThatChangedEmailList`) may be empty:

```
Map<String, User> usernameChangeToUserMap = CommunityUsersManagerUtil.getCommunityUsersForContactsByUserName(contactsThatChangedEmailList);
```

---

Then, the getCommunityUsersForContactsByUserName method puts together a list of usernames from the contact list. In this scenario, that set of Strings would also be empty. That empty string is then used in a query which will return 0 results.

```
public static Map<String, User> getCommunityUsersForContactsByUserName(List<Contact> contacts){
    Set<String> usernames = new Set<String>();
    for(Contact con : contacts){
            usernames.add(generateUsername(con));
    }

    List<User> users = [SELECT IsActive, ID, ContactID, Username FROM User WHERE username in: usernames AND ProfileID =:communityProfileIDStatic ];
    Map<String, User> result =  new Map<String, User>();
    for(User u: users){
        result.put(u.username, u);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

> **Ultimate Question:** The above scenario, even though it returns 0 results, still counts as 1 of 100 available SOQL queries in a
>   transaction, correct?
>
> If so, I would like to begin working on wrapping all of these Util
>   classes in an if(!list.IsEmpty){} block to stop them from running
>   unnecessarily and bogging down my query limits

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does SOQL query get consumed when querying from an empty set?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/162261/2995)

Comment: I think it's because in order to get that 0 record count as the result it would still need to hit the database and come back. Hence it is counted against the SOQL count governor limit. As you correctly pointed out, it is always better to check the list before performing the SOQL query.

Comment: Damn @AdrianLarson, definitely a duplicate. I searched for 15 minutes and didn't find that *sigh*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quick check using execute anonymous shows that indeed it's count as one of 100 queries.

As for second part - yes, it's better to optimize using that approach.

[image: Example]